# How to disable alt+tab thumbnails in Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome

I'm not sure if it's possible to disable the thumbnails that we get with Ubuntu Lucid (Gnome UI), or if I installed something that enabled it and just can't seem to remember what it was. Does anyone know how to disable them?

Also, if I installed them somehow, then it would have been by installing some kind of Apple interface imitator. Anyone know which program I might uninstall to disable this?

Comment: Screenshot, please.

Comment: Hello71 posted a screenshot below. That's exactly what I'm seeing. Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the script Mac4Lin (from http://maketecheasier.com/turn-ubuntu-lucid-mac-os-x/2010/06/01) was the culprit.

I just ran the uninstaller and it removed the thumbnails... after that though, Gnome was broken so I had to remove all the following to reset Gnome to default values:

```
.gnome2
.gconf
.gconfd
.gnupg
.gnome2-private
```

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot of the thumbnails (I think):

[image: Alt+tab thumbnails]

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm seeing. Thanks Hello71

Comment: Any idea how to remove them?

Comment: See my answer, you can disable them in "ccsm".

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it - you need to run the `gconf-editor /apps/metacity` command, and set `compositing_manager` to false.

Or in a terminal run:

```
gconftool-2 -s --type bool /apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager false
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to compiz? Start the compiz configuration editor (command: "ccsm"), scroll down to "Window Management" and wildly toggle stuff until you get back the behaviour that you expect.

**edit**:
You want the *Static application switcher* box enabled. Disable the other *switchers* first.